# Groff long umlaut

Tags: linux, pdf, groff

I'm Hungarian and I want to use groff to write good-loking pdf files, the problem is even though I used:

```
groff -k -ms test.ms -T pdf > test.pdf
```

eventhough `-k` took care of the? é,á,ü,ö characters it cannot handle the: ű,ő characters, when i try it says (this is an example for the ő character):

```
test.ms:8: warning: can't find special character `u006F_030B'
```

Is there a way I can enable these characters?

Comment: Try adding `-Kutf8` parameter.

Comment: I get the same `can't find special character 'u006F_030B'` error with `-Kutf8` with my groff (version 1.22.3). Could it be that the character is not available in the output font? Maybe the comments or answers on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/623970/writing-vietnamese-in-groff or https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/511881/how-to-write-romanian-special-characters-with-groff might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

See Peter Schaffter's page and automated script for installing new fonts to Groff:

https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/appendices.html

You will need to add a font with the Umlaut characters.

Alternatively, you can use `eqn`:

```
.ds "o $roman{o accent "\(a\""}^$
Erd\*["o]s
```