# How to write romanian special characters with groff?

Tags: pdf, special-characters, groff

I've got myself into experimenting with groff and from the start I found out the romanian special characters I type in vim are all fine (I ran `setxkbmap ro`), but get messed up in the pdf export.

Running

`groff -Tpdf -ms letext.ms > letext.pdf`

instead of ășâțî ĂȘÂȚÎ I get all kinds of other special characters.

Running

`groff -Kutf8 -Tpdf -ms letext.ms > letext.pdf`

some of the characters I want remain, but the others disppear and I get this message in the terminal

```
warning: can't find special character `u0074_0326'
warning: can't find special character `u0061_0306'
warning: can't find special character `u0073_0326'
warning: can't find special character `u0041_0306'
warning: can't find special character `u0053_0326'
warning: can't find special character `u0054_0326'
```

Should I edit the tmacs to get the characters I want? Should I write another tmac with the characters I want and load that instead?

---

**EDIT#1**

As Philip Couling suggested, I wrote ășâțî ĂȘÂȚÎ in a file `letest.txt` and ran `hexdump -C letest.txt` on it.
Here are the results.

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm what character set `letext.ms` is written in.  Preferably write `ășâțî ĂȘÂȚÎ` into a text file with vi and then `hexdump -C testfile.txt` and [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/511881/edit) the result into your question.  Character sets are tricky, you always need to know what you are converting from.

Comment: Here it is. Seems nothing comes out of it on the right side.

Comment: This shows the file is indeed in UTF-8.  This doesn't look like the problem I thought it might be.  In searching I did stumble on this which might give something helpful:  https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/groff/2016-02/msg00007.html

Answer (score 0):

See Peter Schaffter's page and automated script for installing new fonts to Groff:

https://www.schaffter.ca/mom/momdoc/appendices.html

You will need to add a font with the Romanian characters.

E.g. I use DejaVu for the real number symbol ℝ in my Groff documents.